# Laravel5: Change PHP session to laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Change PHP session code to laravel session.

I want to put the item_code passed to the GET into the basket session when the value of status is exceeded by the basket.

It would be easy to think of the logic as shopping mall purchase logic. When the user makes a favorite of 4 items, the value of item_code passed to the basket session is returned by the amount of the item. If the user clicks on the bookmark with the item quantity set to 1, the item_code value passed to the basket session is inserted immediately.

I've tried, but I can not keep up with sessions. Help.

```
switch (trim($_GET['status'])) {
    case "":
        break;
    case "basket":
        if ($_GET['amount'] > 1) {
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['amount']; $i++) {
                $_SESSION['basket'][] = $_GET['item_code'];
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['basket'][] = $_GET['item_code'];
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: What does 'when the value of status is exceed by the basket' actually mean?

Please explain what you want to do in simple terms. Why is `amount` sent by the user in a GET variable? Also what are the possible values of `status`?

Comment: @Mongoose 
It would be easy to think of the logic as shopping mall purchase logic. When the user makes a favorite of 4 items, the value of item_code passed to the basket session is returned by the amount of the item.
If the user clicks on the bookmark with the item quantity set to 1, the item_code value passed to the basket session is inserted immediately.

Comment: Sorry, but to me the phrase "the value of item_code passed to the basket session is returned by the amount of the item" makes no sense. How can the item amount (meaning price?) return an item code? From what I see in the code, 'amount' is both a $_GET and $_POST variable, what is the difference between these? I understand that you want to add the item code into the basket based on some condition, but I don't know what condition you want.

Comment: @MingeunKim I don't think it's clear which part you're having trouble with. The title of the post implies you need help with changing a PHP session to Laravel (I'm not sure this even makes sense, but I haven't used Laravel). But your actual question seems to be requesting help with a condition and handling `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_SESSION` variables.

Comment: @Mongoose There is no _GET, _POST difference in amount.
If the value passed in amount is greater than 1, then the loop is executed according to the value of amount. There is item_code for each amount in key value format.
I want to change my PHP code to laravel.

Example 1) 'amount' => 1, 'item_code' => 123213
Example 2) 'amount' => 2, 'item_code' => 100231

Comment: I'll explain the simple code.
`for($i=1;$i <= 3; $ i ++) {
     $_SESSION['basket'][] = $i;
}
`
The code stores 1, 2, and 3 in the basket session. Please change the code to laravel.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session under "Storing Data" - is this all you're looking for? "Please change the code to laravel." - Note that SO is not a coding service, but we can help point you in the right direction

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones 
Thank you for leading me in the right way.
I've seen the documentation, but I'm not sure how to implement it. TT

Comment: I was confused by the name 'amount' . I thought it meant 'price' of a product, but you are using it for 'quantity' of the item. e.g. add 3x the product into the basket. I don't think you should have both $_POST['amount'] and $_GET['amount'] with the same name. Also, data obtained from $_GET and $_POST data cannot be trusted for business logic. If someone simply changes amount from 0 to 1 in their browser, they could enter it into the basket.

Comment: Per the documentation, can't you just do `session(['key' => 'value']);`? In other words, build up an array of the items to add to the basket and then set the session variable like `session(['basket' => $items]);`.

Comment: Sorry. I seem to have confused the code. I am curious about the code without the GET and POST methods.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones
I want to keep multiple values in a basket session continuously.
Currently there is only one value in that code.